# CSS: Fixed-first-column Table? (CSS only!)

Tags: html, css

I've been trying to figure out a way to take a standard table and create a fixed-column table where the first column is fixed while the rest scrolls. There's a couple ways that I think make sense, so I'll start with that.

The first way that makes sense to me is to simply break the table code format by creating a separate table as the column that we want to be by itself, something like this:

```
<div class="table-container">
    <div class="table-column">
         <table>
              <thead><tr><th>&nbsp;</th></tr></thead>
              <tbody>
                   <tr><td>Side Header 1</td></tr>
                   <tr><td>Side Header 2</td></tr>
                   <tr><td>Side Header 3</td></tr>
                   <tr><td>Side Header 4</td></tr>
                   <tr><td>Side Header 5</td></tr>
                   <tr><td>Side Header 6</td></tr>
              </tbody>
         </table>
    </div>
    <div class="table-column" style="overflow-x: auto;">
         <table>
              <thead>
                   <tr><th>Top Header 1</th><th>Top Header 2</th></tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                   <tr><td>Row 1, Cell 1</td><td>Row 1, Cell 2</td></tr>
                   <tr><td>Row 2, Cell 1</td><td>Row 2, Cell 2</td></tr>
                   <tr><td>Row 3, Cell 1</td><td>Row 3, Cell 2</td></tr>
                   <tr><td>Row 4, Cell 1</td><td>Row 4, Cell 2</td></tr>
                   <tr><td>Row 5, Cell 1</td><td>Row 5, Cell 2</td></tr>
                   <tr><td>Row 6, Cell 1</td><td>Row 6, Cell 2</td></tr>
              </tbody>
         </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

We make the first column have a `<th>` of just blank space so that the styling for the whole table still fits.

What I really want to do though is make this more of a dynamic process... Obviously in that case (especially using the word 'dynamic') I could just use some JS, but there must be a way to do this in CSS... but there doesn't seem to be anything solid online... so I thought I'd give it a go.

The closest I've been able to come is through using `data-attribute:;` and `td::before`, like this:

```
<div class="box-table">
  <table class="text-center hover stripes">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th data-label="Cat 1">Cat 1</th>
        <th>Cat 2</th>
        <th>Cat 3</th>
        <th>Cat 4</th>
        <th>Cat 5</th>
        <th>Cat 6</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td data-label="Col 1">Col 1</td>
        <td>Col 2</td>
        <td>Col 3</td>
        <td>Col 4</td>
        <td>Col 5</td>
        <td>Col 6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td data-label="Col 1">Col 1</td>
        <td>Col 2</td>
        <td>Col 3</td>
        <td>Col 4</td>
        <td>Col 5</td>
        <td>Col 6</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>

<style>
tr > th:first-child,
tr > td:first-child {
  padding: 0;
}
tr > th:first-child::before,
tr > td:first-child::before {
  content: attr(data-label);
  display: inline-block;
  position: fixed;
  background: #fff;
  border-right: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  padding: 0 0.75rem;
}
<style>
```

Here's a fiddle with what I've gotten so far: https://jsfiddle.net/wn5nonu3/

There's 2 issues I've run into:

1. The first is that because I've set the item to fixed, if the overflow of the table allows vertical scrolling then the fixed will obviously stay where they are fixed and appear out of line with the row.
2. The second issue is that I can't seem to style `td::before` (it seems to be showing 'inline' behavior regardless of what I change the `display:;` value to?).

Potential solution to the second problem is to remove the padding causing the row's to be larger, set the first column to a fixed width and add that width to `td::before`. I still can't fix the first problem though.

I thought I'd share in case anyone has any ideas about how this could possibly work, or whether or not the route I'm taking is even really doable?

---

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/wn5nonu3/ (same as one posted above, just for easy finding)

For the record: I know there's a number of great JS options, I just like to limit the amount of scripts I throw on my pages, and this just seems like something that would be useful.

Comment: @AllDani Hi! I did actually add a jsfiddle, I'll throw it at the end to to make it easy to find.

Comment: Sidenote: border-box is love, border-box is life. Hello, box-brother.

Comment: @JacqueGoupil Yes, hello! Lol

Comment: You want like Google sheets frozen column?

Comment: @AllDani Yes preferably. I'm willing to muck around with JS and alternate table formats, but the goal of my question is to do it with a standard table format.

Comment: Perhaps add that to the question so as to give an idea of what you are looking for.

Comment: @AllDani, I'm not sure what else I can add, considering I've already stated my question in the title, given a description of what it is that I'm trying to do, shown my progress up until now, and added a jsFiddle showing the errors that I described. I'm not sure it gets any more clearer than that. Thanks for your input.

Comment: "Like Google sheets frozen column", is what I suggest to add.

Answer (score 1):

One way you could make it is by using two tables with the same style, but it's a little hard to maintain. You have to make sure both tables are on the same line and that there's no space between them. When you just wrap the table with the actual content in a div that scrolls. Honestly, I wouldn't go there unless you really don't want to use JS, but it's your call.

```css
.table-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.table-firstcolon {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.table-firstcolon td,
.table-firstcolon th {
  width: 60px;
}

.table-content-wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  vertical-align: top;
  max-width: calc(100% - 60px);
}

.table-content-wrapper>table {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}


/* Page Setup */

*,
*::after,
*::before {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  height: 100%;
  line-height: 1.5;
  width: 50%;
}

body {
  min-height: 100%;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  /* this style is only for the fiddle, would be '0' */
  width: 100%;
}


/* General Table Styling */

table {
  background: #fdfdfd;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

th {
  font-weight: bold;
}

thead,
tbody,
tfoot {
  border: 1px solid #f1f1f1;
}

th, td {
  padding: 6px;
  text-align: left;
}

thead tr:first-child {
  font-weight: bold;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #eee;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.025);
}

tr:hover td {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.04);
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="table-wrapper">
  <table class="table-firstcolon text-center hover stripes">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>&nbsp;</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th>Row 1</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Row 2</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Row 3</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Row 4</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Row 5</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Row 6</th>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table><!--
--><div class="table-content-wrapper">
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Column A</th>
          <th>Column B</th>
          <th>Column C</th>
          <th>Column D</th>
          <th>Column E</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>A1</td>
          <td>B1</td>
          <td>C1</td>
          <td>D1</td>
          <td>E1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>A2</td>
          <td>B2</td>
          <td>C2</td>
          <td>D2</td>
          <td>E2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>A3</td>
          <td>B3</td>
          <td>C3</td>
          <td>D3</td>
          <td>E3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>A4</td>
          <td>B4</td>
          <td>C4</td>
          <td>D4</td>
          <td>E4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>A5</td>
          <td>B5</td>
          <td>C5</td>
          <td>D5</td>
          <td>E5</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>A6</td>
          <td>B6</td>
          <td>C6</td>
          <td>D6</td>
          <td>E6</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```